# differences between echo""> and > command

Tags: shell, io-redirection, echo

I am new to Linux. There is something that is unclear to me.

What is the difference between `echo "" > logfile` and `> logfile` ?

When I run the first one, the logfile size doesn't become zero and same name file will be created with 1 byte size. For the second one, logfile size will become zero and same name file will be created with 0 byte size.

In what situations should the commands be used differently?

For me, I use it when I want to free up the log files.

Comment: There is also `: > logfile`, which might be a little more portable than just `> logfile` as the latter can behave differently in some shells.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They do essentially the same thing. You're seeing a file size difference because `echo` includes a newline at the end, which takes up a byte. You can stop it with `-n`, so `echo -n "" > logfile` will result in a 0-byte file